# How to export checked rows to another workbook using a button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a workbook1 with tab named [5 Retards + 5 min] and it contains the database that shows outages that exceed 5 minutes.
My goal is to export the checked lines to another workbook2, tab named [Avis] using the "Export" button.

**For instance:**
I check lines A8:A12
[image]

**Then I want the data D8:E12 (the checked rows) to be exported to cell A14 of another workbook, tab "Avis".**

A14 contains a preformatted texte.

[image]

This code is relevant but is destinated for two sheets in the same workbook and is triggered onEdit

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "5 Retards + 5 min" || r.columnStart != 2 || r.rowStart <= 8 || !r.isChecked()) return;
  const dest = e.source.getSheetByName("Avis");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart, 25, 1, 2).copyTo((dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

**EDIT**
Afetr editing the script, I'm having this error.

```
function copyRowswithCopyTo() {
let Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let SourceSheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('5 Retards + 5 min');

let SourceRange = SourceSheet.getDataRange();
if (Spreadsheet.getName() != "5 Retards + 5 min" || SourceSheet.columnStart != 2 || r.rowStart <= 8 || !SourceSheet.isChecked()) return;
let DestSheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Avis retards');
SourceRange.copyTo(DestSheet.getRange(15,1))

}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tanaike : I've found your script that should help me. If you want, I'll appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *"au cours de la période du..."* may be easiest to build with a formula. You can then use `importrange()` or a simple script function to copy the phrases to another spreadsheet.

If you cannot use `importrange()` for some reason, one simple way to structure a script function to copy the values would be to use `Range.getDisplayValues()`, `Array.filter()` and `Range.setValues()`, like this:

```
function copyPhrases() {
  const phrases = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getRange('Phrases!A2:A')
    .getDisplayValues()
    .filter(row => row.join(''));
  const targetRange = SpreadsheetApp
    .openByUrl('http://...')
    .getRange('Phrases!A2')
    .offset(0, 0, phrases.length, phrases[0].length)
    .setValues(phrases);
}
```

To build the phrases, you can use a bunch of formulas involving `unique()` and `filter()`. The recently introduced [lambda functions](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/08/named-functions-google-sheets.html) let you do that with a single formula. The following formula first gets various input ranges, then filters `date` and `time` by each `uniqueName` while only including checkmarked rows, then builds a phrase, and finally joins the phrase and the filtered datetimes with the newline character `char(10)`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    checkMark, name, id, date, time, category, uniqueNames, 
    map( 
      uniqueNames, 
      lambda( 
        uniqueName, 
        lambda( 
          filterDate, filterTime, 
          join( 
            " ", 
            uniqueName & ",", 
            "au cours de la période du",
            to_text(min(filterDate)), 
            "au",
            to_text(max(filterDate)) & ",", 
            "vous avez cumulé", 
            rows(filterDate), 
            "retards de plus de 5 minutes:"
          ) 
          & char(10) & char(10) & 
          join(char(10), to_text(filterDate + filterTime)) 
        )(
          filter(date, name = uniqueName, checkMark), 
          filter(time, name = uniqueName, checkMark)
         ) 
      ) 
    )
  )(
    '5 Retards + 5 min'!A8:A, '5 Retards + 5 min'!B8:B, 
    '5 Retards + 5 min'!C8:C, '5 Retards + 5 min'!D8:D, 
    '5 Retards + 5 min'!E8:E, '5 Retards + 5 min'!F8:F, 
    unique(filter('5 Retards + 5 min'!B8:B, '5 Retards + 5 min'!A8:A)) 
   ) 
)
```

An `arrayformula()` wrapper is required here because of the use non-array enabled string concatenation operator `&`, date and time addition with `+`, and `to_text()`.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Upvoted. But the formula explanations are lacking. For eg, there's lot of meta commentary(how to use) than the actual explanation(why the formula works)`There are many ways to write a formula or a bunch of formulas to build phrases.Try the following formula in a new tab in the source spreadsheet:` can be removed without losing much value. A better explanation would be something like: `Using lambda functions, first we get different input ranges, filter the date and time by uniqueNames, then concatenate thec desired ranges with char(10)...Arrayformula is needed, because....`